# Apply a constant to all the fields of a datatype

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have the following datatype

```
data A = A{x::Int,y::Int,z::Int}
```

Is there a way to apply 0 on all the fields to get something like this :

```
let a = A 0 0 0
```

Basically not repeating `0`

The goal at the end would be to use `mempty` from `Sum Int` and do something like this :

```
let a = myfunction mempty :: Sum Int
```

and Have `a == A 0 0 0`

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since coincidentally [`Data.Default`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-default) defines `0` as the default value for `Int`, you can use `data-default-class` to derive it generically with `DeriveAnyClass`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import Data.Default (Default(..))
import GHC.Generics (Generic(..))

data A = A { x, y, z :: Int }
  deriving (Default, Generic)

-- (def :: A) == A 0 0 0
```

You can make this more explicit with `DerivingStrategies` and enforce it with `-Wmissing-deriving-strategies`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingStrategies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wmissing-deriving-strategies #-}

import Data.Default (Default(..))
import GHC.Generics (Generic(..))

data A = A { x, y, z :: Int }
  deriving (Default, Generic)
  deriving anyclass (Default)
  deriving stock (Generic)

-- (def :: A) == A 0 0 0
```

However, `Data.Default` is a class with no laws; it’s better used to indicate the canonical default value of a more complex configuration-like type, because its choices for primitive types are essentially arbitrary.

So if you are able to change the type a bit, you can alternatively use the [`generic-deriving`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-deriving) package, in one of two ways. First, by using `Sum Int` as the type of the fields and deriving `Semigroup` and `Monoid` instances with generics:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import Generics.Deriving.Monoid

data A = A { x, y, z :: Sum Int }
  deriving (Generic)

instance Monoid A where mempty = memptydefault

instance Semigroup A where (<>) = sappenddefault

-- (mempty :: A) == A 0 0 0
-- A 1 2 3 <> A 4 5 6 == A 5 7 9
```

Or second—and this is my preference—by replacing the `data` type with a `newtype` over a tuple of `Int`s, and using `DerivingVia` to derive the instance via `Sum Int`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingVia #-}

newtype A = A (Int, Int, Int)
  deriving (Monoid, Semigroup) via (Sum Int, Sum Int, Sum Int)

-- (mempty :: A) == A 0 0 0
-- A 1 2 3 <> A 4 5 6 == A 5 7 9
```

You can recover the field names using lenses (e.g. `x` is `_1`) or by writing getters and setters manually.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't *one* function, but you can compose `Control.Monad.join` with itself. You also have to unpack the `0` from `mempty` first, since it has type `Sum Int`, not `Int`.

```
let a = (join . join) A (getSum mempty)
```

You could then define `myfunction` has

```
myfunction = (join . join) A . getSum
```

and write

```
let a = myfunction (mempty :: Sum Int)
```

The more direct definition of `myfunction`, though, would simply be

```
myfunction (Sum x) = A x x x
```

Answer (score 4):

## Solution 1: a generic monoid and functor

One idea is that you can easily derive a `Monoid` instance, in particular, `mempty`, for a `Generic` type whose fields are all instances of `Monoid`:

```hs
gmempty :: (Generic a, Monoid (Rep a ())) => a
gmempty = GHC.Generics.to Data.Monoid.mempty
```

(That was just to illustrate; we won't need to use that binding below. This definition actually needs a type annotation on `to`; a complete definition can be found [here in generic-data](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-data-0.8.2.0/docs/src/Generic.Data.Internal.Prelude.html#gmempty).)

However `Int` is not a `Monoid`. One solution is to generalize your type to be a `Functor` (which can be derived with an extension), so you can first instantiate it with a `Monoid`, and then back to `Int` using `fmap`. The choice of monoid doesn't matter in the end, since when you use `fmap` you can pass any function, including a constant one to inject any value you want. So we can choose the `()` monoid as a restricted default:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor, DeriveGeneric #-}
import GHC.Generics (Generic, to)

-- Solution one

data A_ a = A a a a
  deriving (Generic, Functor, Show)

type A = A_ Int

_A0 :: A_ ()
_A0 = to mempty

myfunction :: a -> A_ a
myfunction x = fmap (const x) _A0  -- aka. (Data.Functor.$>)

example :: A
example = myfunction 0
```

## Solution 2: The one-liner library

"Put a value in every field" is exactly what a function in one-liner does (also using generics): `nullaryOp`. This solution has the advantage that you don't need to generalize the `A` type in any way. Keeping the type of fields concrete allows you to [`{-# UNPACK #-}`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#unpack-pragma) them for example.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, TypeFamilies, TypeApplications #-}
import GHC.Generics (Generic)
import Generics.OneLiner (nullaryOp)

-- Solution two

data A' = A' Int Int Int
  deriving (Generic, Show)

myfunction' :: Int -> A'
myfunction' x = nullaryOp @((~) Int) x  -- This requires the `(~) Int` constraint from every field: they must all be of type Int.

example' :: A'
example' = myfunction' 0
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible trick is [using *lens* to generate a prism](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.19.1/docs/Control-Lens-TH.html#v:makePrisms) (which in your case will actually be an iso) between your type and a tuple type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens

data A = A{x::Int,y::Int,z::Int}
    deriving Show
makePrisms ''A
```

```
GHCi> review _A (0,0,0)  -- Or, equivalently, _A # (0,0,0)
A {x = 0, y = 0, z = 0}
```

If you are only interested in filling five or less fields with `mempty`, you can eliminate the repetitiveness by exploiting the `Monoid` instance for tuples:

```
GHCi> import Data.Monoid
GHCi> review _A (over each getSum mempty)
A {x = 0, y = 0, z = 0}
```

Alternatively, if your type is made of fifteen or less fields of the same type, you can use the `Applicative` instances for homogeneous tuples from [*tuples-homogenous-h98*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tuples-homogenous-h98-0.1.1.0/docs/Data-Tuple-Homogenous.html):

```
GHCi> import Data.Tuple.Homogenous
GHCi> review _A (untuple3 (pure 0))
A {x = 0, y = 0, z = 0}
```

For a more general solution, your best bet is reaching directly for generics, as in [Li-yao Xia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61030794/2751851).